# Warnings with a new Xcode project using FMDB, SqliteCipher and CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, fmdb, sqlcipher

I have installed CocoaPods.. and loaded the workspace as instructed.

I am getting these warnings which I do not understand, here is an example:

Pods-CipherDatabaseSync-SQLCipher
sqlite.c
/Users/admin/Code/CipherDatabaseSync/Pods/SQLCipher/sqlite3.c:24035:13: Ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX'

I have looked around for a couple of hours and I am stumped at what I need to do, can someone please point me in the direction of somewhere that will provide some insight?

Thanks.

Comment: appears to be just warning, so is there a problem to build it or run ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sqlite.c file it looks as if MIN and MAX are trying to be defined in two different areas of the file. The first time on line `214`

```
/* Macros for min/max. */
#ifndef MIN
#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#endif /* MIN */
#ifndef MAX
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
#endif  /* MAX */
```

Then secondly at line `8519`

```
/*
** Macros to compute minimum and maximum of two numbers.
*/
#define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
#define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
```

I commented out where they define it the second time and all of the warnings went away after cleaning and building the project again.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `MAX` and `MIN` macro definitions from the sqlite3.c file, since they are already defined in system headers.

Answer (score 1):

Issue Solution:
Open Xcode project Build settings

add `“-Wno-ambiguous-macro”` into  `“Other C flags”`